# Having difficulty to understand the implication of the big parentheses in an equation

Tags: optimization, notation

What do the big parentheses imply in the following equation?

\begin{equation}
\nabla f(\upsilon^{k},\gamma^{k})^T \left(
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \upsilon - \upsilon^{k} \\
                  \gamma - \gamma^{k}
                \end{array}\right)
              + f(\upsilon^{k},\gamma^{k}) \leq \alpha, \forall (\upsilon^{k},\gamma^{k}) \in U
\end{equation}

I want to know how I should interpret the following part in the formula:
\begin{equation}
\left(
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \upsilon - \upsilon^{k} \\
                  \gamma - \gamma^{k}
                \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: $$\left( \begin{matrix} a\\b \end{matrix} \right)$$ denotes a column vector, and $$(x,y) \left( \begin{matrix} a\\b \end{matrix} \right) = xa+yb$$ denotes the usual row-by-column multiplication (which is nothing but the usual scalar product).

Comment: Yep. Now I got it. Thanks.  One mroe question.  $\nabla f(\upsilon^{k},\gamma^{k})^T$ gives partial derivatives of function $f$ with respect to the variable $\upsilon^{k}$ and $\gamma^{k}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you have understood it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis around

\begin{equation}
\left(
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \upsilon - \upsilon^{k} \\
                  \gamma - \gamma^{k}
                \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

represent a column vector of coordinates

$$v-v^k$$

and

$$\gamma-\gamma^k.$$